# Swap lat lon and group by square brackets

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have A file which is having data like

```
input.csv
1;1.30453 103.83589;1.306663 103.83587;1.30 103.5;1.30693 103.83883;1.30709 103.835793;1.30725 103.835757;1.30741 103.83572;1.30753 103.8798
2;1.353 103.83589;1.306663 103.83587;1.30693 103.83583;1.30709 103.835793;1.30725 103.835757;1.30741 103.83572;1.30753 103.835
3;1.30653 103.83589;1.306663 103.83587;1.306797 103.83585;1.3693 
.....
```

I am trying to convert this file to be in the format (I swap the lat and long values position and group them by a square bracket and seperate them by a comma)

```
output.csv

1,[103.83589,1.30453],[103.83587,1.306663],[103.5,1.30],[103.83883,1.30693],[103.835793,1.30709],[103.835757,1.30725],[103.83572,1.30741][103.8798,1.30753]
```

.... and so on.

Comment: Is `103.835871.30693` on line 2 of the input a misspelling? Also, there are seemingly random spaces added to the output, or is that also misspelling?

Comment: Sorry for the Misspelling.Updated the question

Comment: mmm you probably meant to add a `;` on the input rather than a space.(?) Is `awk` a requirement (given that this one is much easier with `sed`)

Comment: No awk is not a requirement.sed is fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/;\([0-9.]*\) \([0-9.]*\)/,[\2,\1]/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

can do the job but in 2nd line there is `1.306663 103.83587 1.30693 103.83583` group which has no `;` separator. If it is not a misprint script should be modified as

```
sed 's/[; ]\?\([0-9.]\+\) \([0-9.]\+\)/,[\2,\1]/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

which produce

```
1,[103.83589,1.30453],[103.83587,1.306663],[103.5,1.30],[103.83883,1.30693],[103.835793,1.30709],[103.835757,1.30725],[103.83572,1.30741],[103.8798,1.30753]
2,[103.83589,1.353],[103.83587,1.306663],[103.83583,1.30693],[103.835793,1.30709],[103.835757,1.30725],[103.83572,1.30741],[103.835,1.30753]
3,[103.83589,1.30653],[103.83587,1.306663],[103.83585,1.306797];1.3693
```

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed 4.2.2`, you'd use a simple `sed` script, like the following:

```
sed 's/\([0-9.]\+\) \([0-9.]\+\)/[\2,\1]/g;s/;/,/g' < input.csv > output.csv
```

It needs backslashes for parentheses and `+` in the match pattern (as well as the numbers in the replacement) to make `sed` regard them as meta characters.

The script consists of two exhaustive replacements for each line: firstly replacing two number-and-dot sequences separated by space with those sequences in opposite order, separated by comma and enclosed in brackets; secondly replacing semi-colon with comma.

Though, with the dual use of `,` in the output, it might not be easily loaded as a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -F'\s+|;' -pale '$" = ",";
   $_ = "$F[0],[" . join("],[", map { "@F[2*$_,2*$_-1]" } 1 .. @F/2) . "]";
' yourfile
```

## Brief

```
The field separator are set at multiple whitespaces or semicolon. Then
excepting for the 1st field, the rest come in pairs. So keeping aside
($F[0]) we look at 2 fields at a time, flip them, & join all these pairs
with "],[".
```